# At its highest or in its highest

Tags: grammar, prepositions, context

So, I have been writing this text about agriculture and farming and I got stuck with this sentence.

> When the population is in its highest...

Should I say "in its highest" or  "at its highest"? I know that preposition depends on context but I really don't understand which one of them I need to use here.

Comment: When the population is at its [carrying capacity](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/topics/resource-library-carrying-capacity/?q=&page=1&per_page=25) ... ?

Comment: "at its highest" sounds more natural, although I'm struggling to find any references to justify that.